# Improving multiple findall executions in Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to improve the usage of multiple executions (~20 times the below for..loop) of the same `findall` in my Python code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

obj = etree.parse(...)
for goal in obj.findall('handle/goal'):
    for rule in goals.findall('rule'):
        ...
```

I have done already some changes. I do now same the outcome in a list and can re-use the list:

```
rule_list = []
for goal in obj.findall('handle/goal'):
    for rule in goal.findall('rule'):
        rule_list.append(rule)
```

Which now I am using this rule_list in all the for..loops (~20 for..loops), like:

```
for rule in rule_list:
    ...
```

Now, although I did this changes, I didn't saw a big gain of the elapsed time, only <5%.

So, I wonder what else can I do? Which other design technique can I use in python to make this faster?

1. Solution += :

```py
    d0 = time.time()
    for goal in obj.findall('handle/goal'):
        rule_list += goal.findall('rule')
    dt = time.time() - d0
    print('time +=(findall): %0.4f' % dt)
    
    time +=(findall): 0.0019s
```

2. Solution iter/append:

```py
    d0 = time.time()
    for goal in obj.iter('handle/goal'):
        rule_list.append(goal.findall('rule'))
    dt = time.time() - d0
    print('time append(iter/findall): %0.4f' % dt)
    
    time append(iter/findall): 0.0089s
```

3. Solution append (two for..loops):

```py
    d0 = time.time()
    for goal in obj.findall('handle/goal'):
        for rule in goal.findall('rule'):
            rule_list.append(rule)
    dt = time.time() - d0
    print('time append(findall): %0.4f' % dt)

    time append(findall): 0.0034s
```

So, it seems the first solution is the fastest with have seen until now.

Comment: What is `text`?

Comment: `text` is the entry of a huge xml file.

Comment: How come you access `.findall()`  on a String variable?

Comment: Hm, findall() finds *all* the matches and returns them as a list of strings, with each string representing one match. It does sound a good first solution, but correct me what else can I use!?

Comment: **`re.findall`** finds *all* the matches. It is not clear what *your* **`text.findall(...)`** does here. Please add more code to see what you have.

Comment: I have updated with  some more information.

Comment: Design technique for what? It is not clear what you are trying to do. The question only contains fragments of code. There is nothing that we can reproduce.

Comment: I guess my question is more if other search techniques are faster then findall. Do you have any opinion about any other approach like regex or not using a list to store the results?

Comment: This needs to be judged according to the characteristics of your XML file, so we mean that it will be more helpful for you to paste some XML code.